# System = {A, B, C} How to use Print command in mathematica to get: A=0, B=0, C=0

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How to use Print command in mathematica to get following results:

If System={A,B,C} then I need output after using print command A=0,B=0,C=0.

Comment: There is a [specialized Mathematica SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) community. Your question will probably get much more attention there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need command: which uses "System" instead of "a, b,c".

Comment: Unfortunately, Print[Thread[System==0]] does not work.